# Join multiple table in one join in propel

Tags: mysql, join, propel

I've been all over the web looking for answers on this. I hope someone here could help me with this.

I am trying to compose the query below using propel. Is possible?

```
SELECT * FROM table1
LEFT JOIN (table2, table3) ON (
     table1.id = table2.foreign_id 
     AND table2.foreign_id = table3.id
);
```

Comment: Post some sample data and expected results for the sample data. I'm sure the SQL can be figured out.  I do still have a concern that you shouldn't be mixing the `,` join notation with the ANSI-92 Join notation using the Join keyword; but maybe propel does something different.

Comment: I'm note sure on your stand on the join notation because the two produces different results. I actually tried just using two separate joins instead of one but results were different since Im using a left join. It will work for inner join. But unfortunately that's not what Im looking for.  Anyway, thank you for the reply, I have decided to just use custom sql and hack the s*** out of propel.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
Table1Query::create()
    ->useTable2Query(null, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN)
    ->useTable3Query(null, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN)
    ->endUse()
    ->endUse()
    ->find();
```

Comment: Yep tried it. Produces different sql query. I just read from propel that it is not possible. The only way right is custom sql.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a view, then based on the view, create a model with `readonly=true` and `skipSql=true` attributes.